# Logical vector in R based on previous row

Tags: r

I would like to select a subset of a vector based on the value in the previous row.  Is this something that is possible without a loop?  More specifically, using time series notation (I made up the 2nd line), I am looking to get y

```
x = c(-2,3,-1,2,8,)
y = x(t)[x(t)>0, x(t-1)<0, x(t)-x(t-1)>2]
y  
[1] 3
```

I don't really need a solution for y as I can always loop it. But would be very interested to know if there is a shift operator or something similar for logical vector indexing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I found to accomplish what I would have liked

```
x = c(-2,3,-1,2,8)
x = zoo(x)
y = x[x>0 & lag(x,-1)<0 & (x-lag(x,-1))>2]
y
2 4 
3 2
```

It very elegantly handles lag(x,-i) without you having to resize your vector

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are looking for. But for this simple purpose, you can use:

```
x <- c(-2,3,-1,2,8)
x1 <- x[-length(x)]
z <- x[-1]
y <- z[z>0 & x1<0 & (z-x1)>2]
y
```

For operating on many 'x(t-i)', I don't know an elegant way, but you could try to wrap the uggly code in a function and then just call `fts(x)`

```
fts <- function(x){
  xmat <- sapply(1:10,function(i){
    x[-1:i]

  })
......
}
```

Also, for `'x(t)-x(t-1)'`, you can use `diff(x)`; for `x(t)-x(t-i)` you can use `diff(x,lag=i)`

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply and it works well.  But I was hoping to see if there was a way to do it directly on the x vector itself.  Because in this case, if I needed to include x(t-2) x(t-3)... it would mean defining many other vectors and the code becomes very ugly

Comment: I guess you can set up a function to wrap up the ugly code and then call the function on your vector.

Comment: duh! Just realised that `x[-1]` is a better way of writing `x[2:length(x)]` as I did in my answer, ditto `x[-length(x)]` for `x[1:(length(x)-1)]`.

Comment: @hjw I think this is either / or. You _either_ have a vectorized approach, which involves multiple vectors, _or_ you have a function that you call in a loop, on a single vector.

Answer (score 1):

Not much different than the other answer, but a bit more compact:

```
x[x > 0 & 
    c(FALSE, head(x,-1) < 0) & 
    c(FALSE, diff(x) > 2)]
```